# Object of Class inheriting LabelFrame doesnt show up (tkinter)

Tags: python, class, tkinter, inheritance, widget

Basically I have a class that inherits from LabelFrame, I want it to show up on the window itself, but I don't see it at all, it doesn't even show up on the window no matter what I do

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root['bg'] = 'white'
root.state('zoomed')

class CharacterFrame(LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, skin_img, requirement, desc):
        super().__init__(master=master, bg='grey29')
        self.desc = Label(self, text=desc)

default_char_frame = CharacterFrame(master=root, desc='Default Character.', requirement=0, skin_img='')
default_char_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nse')

root.mainloop()
```

ok, so i was stupid for not implementing the actual code itself, but ill do it now (This isnt actual source code, just the important code, still has same error as actual code):

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root['background'] = 'white'
root.state('zoomed')

class SkinFrame(LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, skin_img, requirement, desc):
        super().__init__(master=master, bg='grey29')
        self.desc = Label(self, text=desc)
        self.desc.pack()

def show_chars():
    button_grid.grid_forget()
    skin_lib.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nws')

    button_skin0 = Button(skin_lib, text="Skin1", relief="flat", width=15, fg="white", bg="darkgrey", command=lambda: show_char_frame(prev, default_char_frame), font=("Arial", 29, "italic"))
    button_skin0.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(0,10))

    back = Button(skin_lib, text="Back", width=15,  relief="flat", fg="white", bg="maroon", font=("Arial",29,"italic"),
                  command=lambda: [skin_lib.grid_forget(), button_grid.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nws')])
    back.grid(row=100, column=0)

def show_char_frame(prev, char_frame):
    skin_lib.grid_forget()
    default_char_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nse')

default_char_frame = SkinFrame(master=root, desc='Default Skin.', requirement=0, skin_img='')

Label(root, text="Game Title", width=68, relief="flat", bg="white", fg="grey", font=("Arial",26,"italic")).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='n')

button_grid = LabelFrame(root, bg='grey29', relief="groove", pady=10, padx=10)
button_grid.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nws')

skin_lib = LabelFrame(root, bg='grey29', relief="groove", pady=10, padx=10)

skins = Button(button_grid, text="Skins", width=15, relief="flat", fg="white", bg="navy", command=show_chars, font=("Arial", 29, "italic"))
skins.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(0,10))

previous_skinframe

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed to pack() label to add in control

```
self.desc.pack()
```

this is complete code

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root['bg'] = 'white'
root.state('zoomed')

class CharacterFrame(LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, skin_img, requirement, desc):
        super().__init__(master=master, bg='grey29')
        self.desc = Label(self, text=desc)
        self.desc.pack()


default_char_frame = CharacterFrame(master=root, desc='Default Character.', requirement=0, skin_img='')
default_char_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nse')

root.mainloop()
```

in this code what I add `self.desc.pack()` to show

this is output
[image]